# How to export android app user reviews daily?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-play, review

It is clear how to export monthly reviews reports from Google Cloud Storage with gsutil. But [the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en#export_ratings_and_reviews) says that reports are generated daily. Is there any way to access these daily reports? I was thinking about another folder, but don't anything useful there:

```
$ gsutil.py ls gs://pubsite_prod_rev_myappid
gs://pubsite_prod_rev_myappid/earnings/
gs://pubsite_prod_rev_myappid/payouts/
gs://pubsite_prod_rev_myappid/reviews/
gs://pubsite_prod_rev_myappid/sales/
```

Comment: That link says: "Reports are generated daily, accumulated in monthly CSV files, and stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket." so I think that you can only see one CSV file per month which everyday changes including the daily report.

Comment: @Adrián, good idea, will try to check that.